# Check if an object is order-able in python?

Tags: python, types, typechecking

How can I check if an object is orderable/sortable in Python?

I'm trying to implement basic type checking for the `__init__` method of my binary tree class, and I want to be able to check if the value of the node is orderable, and throw an error if it isn't. It's similar to checking for hashability in the implementation of a hashtable.

I'm trying to accomplish something similar to Haskell's `(Ord a) => etc.` qualifiers. Is there a similar check in Python?

Comment: I was going to do that, but there are many many places I'd have to catch exceptions - I'd rather just check once, even though it goes against the "better to ask for forgiveness than permission" idiom.

Comment: Also, even if two objects implement all of the comparison operators, that doesn't mean that they can be compared. Worse yet, even if two objects *can* be compared, if they don't explicitly define the comparison methods, the comparison isn't guaranteed to be stable across script executions. This seems like a design problem to me. Why are you checking for this in the first place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to know if an object is **sortable**, you must check if it implements the necessary methods of comparison.

In **Python 2.X** there were two different ways to implement those methods:

1. cmp method (equivalent of compareTo in Java per example)

   `__cmp__(self, other)`: returns >0, 0 or <0 wether self is more, equal or less than *other*
2. rich comparison methods

   `__lt__, __gt__, __eq__, __le__, __ge__, __ne__`

   The sort() functions call this method to make the necessary comparisons between instances (actually sort only needs the `__lt__` or `__gt__`  methods but it's recommended to implement all of them)

In **Python 3.X** the `__cmp__` was removed in favor of the rich comparison methods as having more than one way to do the same thing is really against Python's "laws".

So, you basically need a function that check if these methods are implemented by a class:

```
# Python 2.X
def is_sortable(obj):
    return hasattr(obj, "__cmp__") or \
           hasattr(obj, "__lt__") or \
           hasattr(obj, "__gt__")

# Python 3.X
def is_sortable(obj):
    cls = obj.__class__
    return cls.__lt__ != object.__lt__ or \
           cls.__gt__ != object.__gt__
```

Different functions are needed for Python 2 and 3 because a lot of other things also change about unbound methods, method-wrappers and other internal things in Python 3.

Read this links you want better understanding of the sortable objects in Python:

- http://python3porting.com/problems.html#unorderable-types-cmp-and-cmp
- http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html#the-old-way-using-the-cmp-parameter

PS: this was a complete re-edit of my first answer, but it was needed as I investigated the problem better and had a cleaner idea about it :)

Comment: This seems like an appropriate use case for `is not` instead of `!=`, otherwise, good answer. Thank you.

Comment: @sortfiend I completely reedited my answer. I may be breaking some rules at stackoverflow or something :p but I investigated be problem and got a much cleared idea about the subject. I think the answer is much cleaner now.

Comment: oh and one more thing: the function that I suggested in the first answer wasn't really working at all. These ones seem to cover all cases now.

Answer (score 3):

While the explanations in answers already here address runtime type inspection, here's how the static types are annotated by [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed). They [start](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/f4ae363b564de69bfad4b4346204a25a99cd6642/stdlib/_typeshed/__init__.pyi#L38) by defining a collection of comparison [`Protocol`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol), e.g.

```py
class SupportsDunderLT(Protocol):
    def __lt__(self, __other: Any) -> bool: ...
```

which are then collected into [rich comparison](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0207/) sum types, [such as](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/f4ae363b564de69bfad4b4346204a25a99cd6642/stdlib/_typeshed/__init__.pyi#L54)

```py
SupportsRichComparison = Union[SupportsDunderLT, SupportsDunderGT]
SupportsRichComparisonT = TypeVar("SupportsRichComparisonT", bound=SupportsRichComparison)
```

then finally these are used to type e.g. the `key` functions of [`list.sort`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/f4ae363b564de69bfad4b4346204a25a99cd6642/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L849):

```py
@overload
def sort(self: list[SupportsRichComparisonT], *, key: None = ..., reverse: bool = ...) -> None: ...
@overload
def sort(self, *, key: Callable[[_T], SupportsRichComparison], reverse: bool = ...) -> None: ...
```

and [`sorted`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/f4ae363b564de69bfad4b4346204a25a99cd6642/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L1463):

```py
@overload
def sorted(
    __iterable: Iterable[SupportsRichComparisonT], *, key: None = ..., reverse: bool = ...
) -> list[SupportsRichComparisonT]: ...
@overload
def sorted(__iterable: Iterable[_T], *, key: Callable[[_T], SupportsRichComparison], reverse: bool = ...) -> list[_T]: ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Regrettably it is not enough to check that your object implements **lt**.
numpy uses the '<' operator to return an array of Booleans, which has no truth value. SQL Alchemy uses it to return a query filter, which again no truth value.
Ordinary sets uses it to check for a subset relationship, so that

```
set1 = {1,2}
set2 = {2,3}
set1 == set2
False
set1 < set2
False
set1 > set2
False
```

The best partial solution I could think of (starting from a single object of unknown type) is this, but with rich comparisons it seems to be officially impossible to determine orderability:

```
 if hasattr(x, '__lt__'):
     try:
         isOrderable = ( ((x == x) is True) and ((x > x) is False)
                         and not isinstance(x, (set, frozenset)) )
     except:
         isOrderable = False
 else:
     isOrderable = False
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

As far as I know, all lists are sortable, so if you want to know if a list is "sortable", the answer is yes, no mather what elements it has.

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 5
        self.b = "asd"

c = C()    
d = True

list1 = ["abc", "aad", c, 1, "b", 2, d]
list1.sort()
print list1
>>> [<__main__.C instance at 0x0000000002B7DF08>, 1, True, 2, 'aad', 'abc', 'b']
```

You could determine what types you consider "sortable" and implement a method to verify if all elements in the list are "sortable", something like this:

```
def isSortable(list1):
    types = [int, float, str]
    res = True
    for e in list1:
        res = res and (type(e) in types)
    return res

print isSortable([1,2,3.0, "asd", [1,2,3]])
```

Comment: I think I've been unclear. I want a check for order-ability, so `7` should pass, but `[]` shouldn't, because you can't sort a list of lists organically, but you can sort a list of integers.

Comment: Not exactly. What I went to know is whether I could sort a list of objects of the type of the object, not whether I can sort the object itself. EDIT: I want the opposite behavior of the current answer. [] should not pass and 1 should. (but not 'opposite' enough to just use not).

Comment: What I'm really looking for seems next to impossible, but this looks to be as close as it gets.

Comment: For python 3.4: `l = [object(), object()]; l.sort()` we have `TypeError: unorderable types: object() < object()`

Comment: Python 3.8.6, `[{1:2}, {3:4}].sort()` yields `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'`